# NVA: rewrite before or after Varnish?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite, varnish, cache

I'm planning an NVA server system (Nginx-Varnish-Apache), where request are routed through in that order. Apache would be serving WordPress CMS or similar.

I'm wondering where to apply additional rewrite rules (as in add custom rewrites to conf by hand). Should rewrites be done at the Nginx end or the Apache end? Which is easier to implement and which would perform better? Or should the rewrites be done in Varnish?

As I see it all rewrites could be done in Apache, as Varnish will serve these rewritten requests as is, lowering the need of processing(?) before serving pages.

Am I right in this, or is it better to actually rewrite before requesting the pages from Varnish (which gets pages from Apache)? This requires the server to actually check and do the rewrite on each request. But this way all rewrites would be "instant" without requiring cache purging at Varnish.

#### Example 1:

I have a WordPress multisite with a subdomain installation (subsites go as `foo.domain.com`, `bar.domain.com`, `baz.domain.com` and so on). The multisite root site should reside in `www.domain.com`, but the actual content is available at `domain.com` (no `www`).

WordPress itself handles the subsite subdomain mapping (database table switching), but the no-www to www rewrite should be done manually. Where would this rewrite be done?

#### Example 2:

I have a certain template on the backend that might be rewritten sometimes, and sometimes not. Lets say its `www.domain.com/offer/12345/?available=0` and sometimes we might want to rewrite the URL to redirect to a template `www.domain.com/offers` with data about unavailability.

This rewrite would come and go, depending on whether the site has content for the unavailable offers situation. Would this rewrite work better before or after Varnish?

(I know this redirect should be done in the site's internal logic in order to automate it, but for the sake of this example let's assume it should be rewritten by the server itself.)

Comment: An old question, but still interested why this order NVM? It does not make much sense. It should be VN or VA. ... As for rewrites - they should be done as early as possible if they are offloading the load on the stack (for example, you are redirecting a user, it should be done at the first layer, since there is non need for any other server to process that request or pass it through the network).